# Adding an attribute to a part of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following string:

```
var string = "hello @johndoe how are you?";
```

how can I delimit the part of the string containing "johndoe" and add tags to, to get a result like this

```
"hello <div class="something">@johndoe</div> how are you?"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may go for a regex like

```
string = string.replace(/(@[^\s$]+)/g, '<div class="something">$1</div>')
```

Comment: This looks good aswell if you're trying to target all @ keywords.

Comment: @arun `/(@[^\s$])/` will only replace one character. It should have a '+'. like:  `/(@[^\s]+)/` or `/(@[^\s$]+)/`

Comment: @DrGeneral yes... copied the wrong version from my console :(

Comment: How can I use this method to get just "amilajack"? That would also be really helpful! Thank you so much!

Comment: @AmilaJack `name = string.match(/@([^\s$]+)/)[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You could do a replace:

```
string = string.replace('@johndoe', '<div class="something">@johndoe</div>');
```

This will only replace one instance though, to replace all you should use regex:

```
var re = new RegExp('@johndoe', 'g');
string = string.replace(re, '<div class="something">@johndoe</div>');
```

In a function:

```
function wrapDiv(string, accountName) {
    var re = new RegExp(accountName, 'g');
    string = string.replace(re, '<div class="something">' + accountName + '</div>');
    return string;
}

alert(wrapDiv('hello @johndoe and @mikesmith how are you?', '@johndoe'));
```

---

PHP isn't tagged in the question, but as per your comment - here's a PHP alternative (no need for regex here as `str_replace()` will replace all occurrences by default):

```
function wrapDiv($string, $accountName) {
    return str_replace($accountName, '<div class="something">' . $accountName . '</div>', $string);
}

$string = wrapDiv('hello @johndoe and @mikesmith how are you?', '@johndoe');
echo $string; // hello <div class="something">@johndoe</div> and @mikesmith how are you?
```

Comment: The string is outputted with php so @johndoe isn't a variable in js. Is it possible to do this dynamically?

Comment: Why don't you do it with PHP then?

Comment: The issue is that the username is not inserted dynamically with php. Comments are saved as plain text. In the DB, a row would have "hello @johndoe how are you?"